# Make view disable after some boolean value in django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

## models.py

```
class One(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    one = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ses = models.IntegerField()
    occupied = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have `occupied` boolean field which is `False` by default. I want to make respective views disable or only read only after occupied is made `True`

## serializers.py

```
class OneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = One
        field = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('user',)
```

## views.py

```
class OneView(APIView):
    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        user = request.user
        apt = One.objects.filter(user=user)
        if type(apt)==Response:
            return apt
        return Response(OneSerializer(apt).data)

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        serializer  = OneSerializer(data=request.data, context = {'request':request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            serializer.save(user=user)
            return Response(OneSerializer(serializer.instance).data, status=201)
        return Response(serializer.errors, statusl=400)
```

How do I make such feature making occupied True, make the respective view only readonly to  owner user?

Comment: so if the `occupied` is True the user cant post any thing, right ?

Comment: yeah after occupied is made true. User cannot post.